# PHP script not working in server

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make a chat messenger for personal use. The messenger seems to work fine in my localhost but when i upload it into my server, there the auto refresh of the **show** div is not working.

Here are the codes:

**kmchat.php**

```
 <?php session_start() ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>KM</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#show").load('kmmessage.php')
}, 1000);//2sec = 2000, 1sec = 1000
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <fieldset style="width:490px;height:auto;border:1px solid blue">
        <center>
        <b><h2 style="color:blue;padding:0px;">Kar Messenger</h2><h3 style="color:blue;padding:0px;">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></h3></b></center>
        <form method="POST" action="">
        <center>
        <textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="message" id="message" style="background:white;border:1px solid blue;color:blue" placeholder="Your message" required autofocus></textarea>
        <br><input style="width:90px;padding:4.5px;font-size:15px;color:blue;" type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send"></center>
        </form>
        <center>
        <div id="show"style="height:auto;width:490px;border:1px solid blue;overflow:auto;background-color:white;color:white;padding-left:5px;">
        </div>
        </center>
        </fieldset>
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST["send"]))
        {
            $servername = "some name";
            $username = "some name";
            $password = "some password";
            $dbname = "some database";
            $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
            $message = $_POST["message"];
            $user = $_SESSION['name'];
            $sql1 = "insert into chattable (name,message) values ('$user','$message')";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Login first..!!';
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**kmmessage.php**

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
    {
        $servername = "some name";
        $username = "some name";
        $password = "some password";
        $dbname = "some database";
        $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        $sql2 = "select name, message from chattable order by slno desc";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
        {
            echo '<span style = "color:blue;">'.$row["name"].': '.$row["message"].'<br><br></span>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: does `kmmessage.php` work when you hit it directly instead of using your AJAX call?

Comment: What specifically fails? Is `$_SESSION['name']` set? You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: have u checked the js console for errors?

Comment: I suddenly noticed that the messages are updating but taking too much time. Any way to reduce it to 1sec???